# Parse MySQL Community Edition 5.7 auto-generated temporary root password in bash shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, centos

I am installing MySQL 5.7 on CentOS 7 (x64) like this:

```
yum localinstall -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm;
yum install -y mysql-community-server;
```

The new version of mysql automatically generates a random root password. This can be found with the following command:

`grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log | tail -1`

e.g. output:

> 2016-01-01T20:51:50.861279Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: s8,arY7l_xQ:

Is there a way to parse the randomly generated root pass `s8,arY7l_xQ:` to a variable from the above command's output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
dan@ebony ~ $ cat file
2016-01-01T20:51:50.861279Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: s8,arY7l_xQ:
dan@ebony ~ $ grep 'temporary.*root@localhost' file | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //'
s8,arY7l_xQ:
dan@ebony ~ $ passwd="`grep 'temporary.*root@localhost' file | sed 's/.*root@localhost: //'`"
dan@ebony ~ $ echo $passwd
s8,arY7l_xQ:
```

Comment: I've tried it, it does not work. Returns empty string.

Comment: looks like in your example the password is actually at the _end_ of the line, not the next line like for some reason I had thought.  Try my update.  I include a test to show it works.